# Compare only day and month with date field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

How to compare only day and month with date field in mysql?
For example, I've a date in one table: `2014-07-10`

Similarly, another date `2000-07-10` in another table.
I want to compare only day and month is equal on date field.

I tried this format. But I can't get the answer

```
select *
from table
where STR_TO_DATE(field,'%m-%d') = STR_TO_DATE('2000-07-10','%m-%d')
and id = "1"
```

Comment: Can't have two `WHERE` clauses in your `SELECT`. Is that a typo?

Comment: k I add it by unknown. Actually I want to compare day and month with date field. How to do this

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use DATE_FORMAT instead:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2000-07-10','%m-%d')
```

yields

```
07-10
```

Here's your query re-written with `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(field, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('2000-07-10', '%m-%d')
AND id = "1"
```

Comment: Sure, but why would you want to convert a date to a string to perform the comparison on the latter if you can avoid to?

Comment: I've 2 table in my db. I want to select records only day and month is equal on both table without consider year

Comment: @John how is that relevant to my comment?

Comment: Is any other method to do this?

Comment: Yes, look at the other answers. Obviously, converting dates into strings to compare them can **only be frowned upon**.

Comment: Nothing wrong with comparing strings here. Comparing strings is done all the time.

Comment: @MarcusAdams while the strings comparison is, of course, fine, it's OP's [first] idea of converting dates into strings for sole comparison purposes that made me flinch.

Answer (score 12):

you can do it with the `DAYOFMONTH` and `MONTH` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(field) = 31 AND MONTH(field) = 12 AND id = 1;
```

**EDIT:**
Of course you can write following too if you want to compare two fields:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
    DAYOFMONTH(field) = DAYOFMONTH(field2) 
    AND MONTH(field) = MONTH(field2) 
    AND id = 1 ...;
```

for further information have a look at the manual:

1. [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
2. [`DAYOFMONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

Comment: No I want to compare two table values. So it is not working here

Comment: SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
    DAYOFMONTH(field) = DAYOFMONTH(field2) 
    AND MONTH(field) = MONTH(field2) 
    AND id = 1 ...;   it is correct

Answer (score 3):

Use [**MONTH**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [**DAY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) functions:

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a 
WHERE a.id = 1 AND MONTH(a.field) = MONTH('2000-07-10') AND 
      DAY(a.field) = DAY('2000-07-10')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`field`, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2000-07-10','%Y-%m-%d'), '%d-%m')
```

also the second `WHERE` is not valid. Anyway you would want to get all rows not only `id=1`

Comment: Downvoted because it seems much more reliable/less likely to break somehow to compare the parts of the dates instead of converting to strings.

Comment: @Azendale I don't think this was about the reliability or likely of something.

Answer (score 0):

where DAYOFMONTH(dtjoin) = '26' AND MONTH(dtjoin) = '11'
Thanks it worked for me

Comment: Please don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).