# get todays birth date from db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am having column `DOB` which have `dob` of person and store it in `(y-m-d)` format. i want to know what will be the query to get today's birth date.
I had tried `date(y-m-d)` but it only show today's date result.
i.e. if there is  `2018-2-20` as `dob` in my db then it will show in my result but if there is `1995-2-20` this date is not shown as result so basically i just want to display who's birthday is today.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: date is data type of column

Comment: So you want to compare only Day and Month and not Year. It has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510108/compare-only-day-and-month-with-date-field-in-mysql

Comment: yes i want to compare only date and month then only i will get birthdays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

**MySQL Query :**

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  YourTable
WHERE 
  DATE_FORMAT(BirthDayField,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
```

*This query convert your `desired date` and `current date` to `m(month)-d(day)` format and compare*

> **Note :** Here `BirthDayField` is column name with data type `DATE`

Details about MySQL [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
 SELECT * 
FROM  persons 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(birthday, 
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) >= DAYOFYEAR(birthday),1,0)
                YEAR)  
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY);
```

I think this will help you to getting the users who have b'day today.

Comment: This will only check if they were born today.

Comment: i tried this as said  before but it gives  result of todays date (including current year) but i want query which will select

Answer (score 0):

first get the current date.

```
$today = date("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

then init the query where you say what should be selected.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM bla WHERE `DOB` = %s", $today);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you try something like this, using a `case` statement to determine if a record is a current birthday

```
select *,
    case when day( date( dob ) )=day( date( now() ) ) and month( date( dob ) )=month( date( now() ) ) then 1
    else 0
    end as 'birthday'
from table
```

Comment: This will only check if they were born today.