# How to convert args[1] to date for input into MySQL DB (Javascript, DiscordJS)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, formatting, discord

I have created a discord bot complete with command handlers. I am trying to make a command which takes args[1] of the user message and inputs this into a MySQL field.

In this case it would be `>birthdayadd @user MM/DD/YYYY`. the current code takes the `args[1]` if it's equal to the length 10 and adds it into the MySQL.

The current problem with this means its not formatted correctly in the mySQL and I can't create a command which sorts and returns the birthdays within certain time span.

How would I convert it so that the args[1] are converted to a date string (taking only the day and month) then inputs into the mySQL column formatted as DATE?

Code below:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, con) => {

    let mention = message.mentions.users.first() || bot.users.get(args[0]);
    if (!mention) return message.reply("You must mention someone or give their ID!");

    con.query(`SELECT bday FROM alltime WHERE user = '${mention.id}' AND guild = '${message.guild.id}'`, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;

        if (!args[1]) return message.reply("You must specify a birthdate to add in the format DD/MM");
        if (args[1].length < 10) return message.reply("format must be DD-MM-YYYY");
        if (args[1].length > 10) return message.reply("format must be DD-MM-YYYY");

        if (args[1].length === 10) {
            con.query(`UPDATE alltime SET bday = '${args[1]}' WHERE user = '${mention.id}' AND guild = '${message.guild.id}'`);
            message.channel.send(`Birthday set to ${args[1]} for ${bot.users.get(mention.id).username}`);
        };

    })
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "birthdayadd",
    usage: "``prefix`` @member DD/MM",
    description: "Add a users birthday into the database",
}
```

```
bot = discord client

con = MySQL connection details
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I recommend you use [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) for formatting and MySQL uses YYYY-MM-DD**

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html)

You can use moment to

1. Take in the user's date string - This accepts multiple different types of dates
2. Format it to YYYY-MM-DD

   ```
   var date = moment("March 17 2004");
   console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
   //2004-03-17
   ```

For getting only the month and day, refer to [Compare only day and month with date field in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510108/compare-only-day-and-month-with-date-field-in-mysql)

Comment: var date = moment(`${args[1]}`);
        console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

moment is not defined?

Comment: Nvm, installed the library. Thanks!!