# PHP and MySQL: Compare only month and day regardless of year in date field

Tags: php, eloquent, sql-date-functions

I have a date field (myDate). Lets say the field has the following date:

2015-01-01
2013-12-31

If the users searches the field (myDate) with the following search parameters:

**From Date**: 2018-12-31      **To Date**: 2019-01-05

I want the query to return the dates listed above 2015-01-01 and 2013-12-31 because they lie within the range of dates (when it comes to month and day) submitted by the user

I tried the following query:

```
$listofUsers->whereRaw("DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(myDate),DAY(myDate))) >= DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(?),DAY(?)))",[$frm,$frm]);
$listofUSers->whereRaw("DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(myDate),DAY(myDate))) <= DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(?),DAY(?)))",[$to,$to]);
```

It works great for dates within the same year, but it fails if the submitted From Date and To Date are in two different years AND To Date month is  smaller than From Date month.

Any idea how to make this work regardless of year

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare only day and month with date field in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510108/compare-only-day-and-month-with-date-field-in-mysql)

Comment: Compare either MONTH(date) and DAY(date) separately, or date formatted as string by pattern %d%m.

Comment: @CBroe the problem is that I have a range of dates that I need to compare with

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query

```
$FromDate  = '2019-02-27';
$ToDate     = '2020-06-26';

SELECT * FROM `tblname` 
WHERE 
DATE(myDate) BETWEEN '$FromDate' AND '$ToDate' 
OR  
DATE(myDate) BETWEEN '$ToDate' AND '$FromDate';



SELECT * FROM `tblname` 
WHERE 
DATE(myDate) BETWEEN '2019-02-27' AND '2020-06-26' 
OR  
DATE(myDate) BETWEEN '2020-06-26' AND '2019-02-27';
```

Comment: This answer does not address the limitation of the search to month and day.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question, but if I understand correctly you want this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE myDate LIKE concat('%', :start_day_of_year, '%')
AND   myDate LIKE concat('%', :end_day_of_year, '%')
```

```php
$users->whereRaw($sql, [
    'start_day_of_year' => substr($fromDate, 5), 
    'end_day_of_year' => substr($toDate, 5), 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### definitions

- From: user-input
- To: user-input
- Target: database-field

#### logic

There are 4 cases you have to cover:

1. From-Year `>` To-Year

   No match, since you dont cover a single day.
2. From-Year `==` To-Year. (standard)

   Target has to be `>=` From `AND` Target has to be `<=` To.
3. From-Year`+1` `<` To-Year (From is more than 1 year relative to To)

   Match all, since you cover more than one year
4. From-Year`+1` `==` To-Year. (From was last year relative to To)

   1. To `>=` From

      Match all since you cover at least a whole year.
   2. Target `>=` From `OR` Target `<=` To

      Match.

#### wrap all together

`NOT(1) AND (2 OR 3 OR (4 AND (4.1 OR 4.2 )))`

#### precourse

We transform day and month to a simple number, where comparison is easy:

`DATE_FORMAT('2000-01-01','%m%d')` will be `0101` => `101`

#### building-blocks

- From-Year `DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y')`
- To-Year `DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y')`
- From `DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')`
- To `DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')`
- Target `DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%m%d')`

#### as sql

```
-- 1
NOT(
    DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y') > DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y')
)
AND
(
    -- 2
    (
        DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y')
        AND
        DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')
        AND
        DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%m%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')
    )
    OR
    -- 3
    (DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y')+1) < DATE_FORMAT(?,'%Y')
    OR
    (
        -- 4
        (DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')+1) = DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')
        AND
        (
            -- 4.1
            DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')
            OR
            -- 4.2
            (
                DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')
                OR
                DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%m%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m%d')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

#### parameters

```
[$frm, $to, $frm, $to, $frm, $to, $frm, $to, $frm, $to, $to, $frm, $frm, $to]
```

You may be able to use named bindings. I dont know. (this will shorten the parameters significantly)

---

Not testet - happy debugging :D